# XPath to find elements that does not have an id or class

Tags: xpath

How can I get all tr elements without id attribute?

```
<tr id="name">...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
//tr[not(@id) and not(@class)]
```

That will give you all `tr` elements lacking both `id` and `class` attributes. If you want all `tr` elements lacking one of the two, use `or` instead of `and`:

```
//tr[not(@id) or not(@class)]
```

When attributes and elements are used in this way, if the attribute or element has a value it is treated as if it's true. If it is missing it is treated as if it's false.

Answer (score 33):

If you're looking for an element that **has** class `a` but **doesn't** have class `b`, you can do the following.

```
//*[contains(@class, 'a') and not(contains(@class, 'b'))]
```

Or if you want to be sure not to match partial.

```
//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' some-class ') and 
not(contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' another-class '))]
```

Answer (score 15):

Can you try `//tr[not(@id)]?`

Answer (score 0):

We can use as follows also for other scenarios :
where we have two element

```
<input type="text">
```

and

```
<input type="text" disabled="">
```

and we want to select second element Then we can go for:

```
//input[not(@disabled)]
```