# XPath logical condition and findall function

Tags: xml, conditional-statements, lxml, elementtree

I am trying to find all XML elements that do *not* have certain type attribute using XPath. The following code shows the relevant part of the XML's structure:

```
<item>
                    <descriptorgroup>
                        <descriptors type="MEA">
                            <descriptor>
                                <mainterm> polyolefin </mainterm>
                            </descriptor>
                            <descriptor>
                                <mainterm> water </mainterm>
                            </descriptor>

<\item>
```

I would like to extract the value of the main terms (in this case polyolefin, water) for all items, where descriptor type is not MEA or MEB (in the first instance, I've been trying to just retrieve these where type is not MEA. I've tried the following code:

`terms = item.findall(".//ns0:descriptors[not(@type ='MEA')]//ns0:mainterm", prefix_map)`,
where the prefix_map specifies the namespace corresponding to ns0.

A modification of this code to `terms = item.findall(".//ns0:descriptors[@type ='MEA']//ns0:mainterm", prefix_map)` successfully finds all items meeting a certain condition (e.g. @type = "MEA"), but upon adding the not, I get an **"invalid predicate" error**.

I saw similar questions, like [XPath to find elements that does not have an id or class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404130/xpath-to-find-elements-that-does-not-have-an-id-or-class), where the syntax of the not condition is clarified, but it seems this condition is not compatible with item.findall? I'm new to lxml and ElementTree and not sure what I can substitute the findall function with for my conditional to work.

Comment: Are you trying to exclude `@type` attibutes or their value? Also, please add a minimum working sample of the xml you are working with,

Comment: Sorry, I've added the information now

Comment: The sample xml in your question is (very) not well-formed and doesn't have any of the necessary namespace information. Disregarding the namespace issue, it may be possible to give you an lxml answer by guessing at the correct xml format, but it may not work with your actual xml.

Comment: @Magdalena the xpath() method lets you use the full power of xpath. https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, `findall()` does not use true XPaths. From the [tutorial](https://lxml.de/2.2/tutorial.html):

> The ElementTree library comes with a simple XPath-like path language
> called ElementPath... However, advanced
> features like value comparison and functions are not available.

To use an XPath function like `not()`, try `terms = item.xpath(".//ns0:descriptors[not(@type ='MEA')]//ns0:mainterm", prefix_map)`